# Dynamically grab text from a h2 and append it to a button

Tags: jquery, append

I have a set of tabs with a h2 in each, I'm now trying to add a button at the bottom of each of the tab's content to move onto the next one. I've manage to do this using the following code:

```
$(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab' rel='" + next + "'>Next</a>");
```

However I now would like to automatically add the title from the h2 after the Next text, so the link text would end up being "Next title text", where title text would change depending on which tab you're on. Guess the first question is, is this possible?

The markup is looking like this:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <p>content here</p>
    <a href="#" class="next-tab mover" rel="2">Next</a>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <p>content here</p>
    <a href="#" class="next-tab mover" rel="3">Next</a>
    <a href="#" class="prev-tab mover" rel="1">Previous</a>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <p>content here</p>
    <a href="#" class="prev-tab mover" rel="2">Previous</a>
</div>
```

So i'm wanting to append the next tabs h2 to the next button and the previous tabs to the previous tab.

So I need something along the lines of

```
$( "h2" ).insertAfter( $( ".next-tab" ) );
```

But it needs to know which h2 to select…

Comment: if you can provide jsfiddle, it would be useful to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$('.mover').each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text() + '(' + $('#tabs-' + $(this).attr('rel')).find('h2').text() + ')');
});
```

here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2y7cemyw/1/

Comment: Hi Caner, I've realised I didn't have quite the correct values in my rel's, any idea how i'd get it to work from this? http://jsfiddle.net/2y7cemyw/2/ seems they start from 0 instead of 1

Comment: you can update your div ids accordingly like `tabs-0`, `tabs-1` and `tabs-2`